# How to upgrade pre 1.12 Android projects

Tags: flutter

what is correct and fully way to upgrade android **kotlin** project here in this article  [enter link description here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects)

only for java `Delete android/app/src/main/java/[your/package/name]/MainActivity.java` what about `/MainActivity.java` when I removed it I'm facing a punch of issues .

Comment: same too..get missing plugin exception...

Comment: @JohnJoe it's about android v2 embedding if you use display your packages one by one and try until catch the plugin that not support embedding 2 or check every packages issues/github and see users maybe one has submit ticket before you

Comment: I using the old embedded method([Embeded v1](https://github.com/vrtdev/flutter_workmanager/blob/master/ANDROID_SETUP_V1.md)), but get this `Tried to automatically register plugins with FlutterEngine (io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@588cce3) but could not find and invoke the GeneratedPluginRegistrant.`